# How to get The thread priority in Windows Kernel?

Tags: windows, kernel, windows-kernel

I am writing a kernel mode driver and I would like to get the priority of a /*user-mode*/ thread (should be a number between 0-15).
I have the PETHREAD.

Comment: [`KeQueryPriorityThread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553062(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: that's the answer, thx!

Answer (score 1):

[KeQueryPriorityThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553062(v=vs.85).aspx) returns the *current* priority of the thread. It does not correspond to the priority given to a thread via [SetThreadPriority](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686277(v=vs.85).aspx). AFAIK, it is the combined priority, i.e. [process priority](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686219(v=vs.85).aspx) + thread priority + dynamic priorities.